# How to convert .NET 4.0 DLL to .NET 3.5 DLL

Tags: c#, dll

I  have C# .NET 3.5 project. I have found some library that is compiled into .NET 4.0 DLL. It is simple library, so maybe they are not using any features specific for .NET 4.0 . I would like to check that and convert library to version .3.5 so I can use it in my project.

How to do that? Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have the source code? Or just the dll file?

Comment: That is 3rd party DLL (no source code).

Comment: If it's a third-party DLL, contact the vendor/author of the DLL and ask them.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using RedGate .NET reflector to decompile the DLL back to a VS project in the language of your choice.  Then switch the framework version down to 3.5 and try rebuilding it.  You may or may not have issues to resolve as a result of doing this.

The other approach would be to create a COM callable wrapper so that your .NET 2.0 code can call into the .NET 4.0 assembly indirectly via COM interop.   I was doing that 7-8 years ago but I don't know how common it is these days.

Comment: I tried to use Reflector just delete attribute "target framework" in dll which says 4.0. But VS2008 would not load the dll. I thought that is all IL, so it shoudl recognize it, but didn't work.

Comment: Decompilation didn't work well. I can not build it. I got 50+ errors when I try to build it.